# My linear function is failing, need help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an initial price (P0) of `$4,5` and a final price of `$16` (P1).

The exercise requires to find a function to get the amount of months needed to reach the $16 (non-accumulative).

n = quantity of months

So, y = f(x) =>

P0 * (1 + x/100) * n = P1

y = n = P1 / (P0 * (1 + x/100))

If x = 255,55%, the months = 1.

But If I apply 20%, the amount of months should be like 12,77 or so, but the function returns 2.96

Where am I failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation should be $P_0*(1+nx/100)=P_1$  Your equation is multiplying the original balance by $n$, not just the interest.